# Mysql Classpath setting in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apache2, mysql, lamp, xampp

I have installed xampp on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am able to use mysql by accessing it through terminal using `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root -p`

But I want to use it directly from terminal like `sachin@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u root -p`

When I try to use it gives me following error:

```
> sachin@ubuntu:~$ mysql -u root -p The program 'mysql' can be found in
> the following packages:  * mysql-client-core-5.5  *
> mariadb-client-core-5.5  * mysql-client-core-5.6  *
> percona-xtradb-cluster-client-5.5 Try: sudo apt-get install <selected
> package>
```

I am new to Ubuntu. I think mysql classpath needs to be set here.

How can I set mysql class path on my Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a symlink. Like so ...

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/mysql /usr/bin/mysql
```

Adding `/opt/lampp/bin/` to your PATH is possible be seems overkill to me but you could also add this to your profile (`~/.bash_profile`)

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin/:
```